# set event on dynamically changed data in field via jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

I have several field

> $("#a1").change(function(){
>   console.log('fire'); });

but when value change not user event not work

> form[0].val = 100;

event not work

how can i catch this change data ?
ps data changes from different places not my code suggestions like trigger('change') not good idea

Answer (score 0):

I do not think that events will fire when you set the value in that fashion.

Does it work when you set the value of the element in the browser?

What you can do is call form[0].change(), and it should work.

Comment: Code where set all values not mine maby has another way cath this change ?

Comment: I think that if you cannot control who is changing the value of the DOM element, then you may be at a loss.  Like jereme said, you would be well served by creating an abstraction that the users must use (by convention only), but even then the DOM is available to all.  You might be able to use a library that uses an observer pattern that will watch for you so you dont have to poll yourself.  I think that Knockout.js has some of these features.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the `value` property will not fire the `change` event.

In fact, your code should be changing `value` and not `val`.

You could call it explicitly after updating it.

```
form[0].value = 100;
form.change();
```

But you mention that is not an option.

The only other way is to poll for changes.

Answer (score 0):

You could define a way of working with the controls inside your form. Create a javascript function that external developers can call to set the value of a given field and make them use that method. Then you can fire change or do whatever you want to your hearts content.